# CSS Transforms - Why does a simple rotation make the image blurry?

Tags: css, image, css-transforms

Why does a simple rotate make an image blurry?

Looking to rotate an image 90deg, but the resulting image is unacceptably blurry.

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

This is the same in both Firefox and Chrome (haven't checked other browsers).

Here is a JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/6d2GT/1/

Are there any workarounds/tricks to minimize the blurring?

--

In case it's computer specific, an image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/EidRE.png

Comment: I'm guessing the rasterization process/anti-aliasing is what causes it.

Comment: for chrome, try adding this : `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @web-tiki still blurry... ...

Comment: I had a close look at your fiddle and you image and I can't see a difference between both "cups" are you shure it doesn't come from the original image?

Comment: @web-tiki, please see the imgur link...that's what I see on my computer. It's not just that image, try changing the image used in JSFiddle and see

Comment: @web-tiki, the image once rotated is no longer crisp

Comment: another random image http://i.imgur.com/JpzwZ0p.png

Comment: Yes I can see it now, I was looking at the blue part witch isn't pixel perfect on both images but when I looked at the black border it is a little blurry on the rotated image

Comment: I think this is just the way the browsers' rendering works, it's not perfect but very fast. Generally in photographs or more complex images the blurring is negligible. For a graphic like in your example you could use SVG, which stays sharp (at least in the 90° steps).

Comment: Try using SVG instead. Here is how http://codepen.io/Izaias/pen/WvWxxv.

Comment: The blur is especially noticeable when rotating not in a factor of 90 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following :

```css
#pic {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translatez(0);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translatez(0);
  margin-top: 50px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%  51%;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/6d2GT/2/

don't forget the needed prefixes

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple!!! You need to make sure your images width and height are even numbers.  You don't need to worry about adding the rotation to the parent, you can apply it directly to the image.

I had the problem just now and the first thing I thought of as it seemed to be fine rotating 180 was that as it rotates 90 it's not aligning correctly due to the odd number of pixels. So it tries to center which in turn causes a blur effect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a scale transform,

```
scale(0.99)
```

seems to help

http://jsfiddle.net/jetRed/6d2GT/3/

Comment: Can potentially use a larger verion of the image for rotations and scale it down...

Answer (score 0):

You must put the image inside another tag and rotate the parent tag. This way the image doesn't appear blur.

**HTML**

```
<div class = "rotate_parent">
    <img ...>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate_parent{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```